# record has one relation to specific other record

Tags: mysql, sql

these are the tables I have:

```
------    ----------     -------
|tags| -- |tagitems|  -- |items|
------    ----------     -------
```

so tags have a m:n relationship with items.

I want to get a list of all tags with an additional boolean column which is created on the fly and holds for each tag the boolean value whether the tag has a relation to an item id I specify or not.

So the desired result is:

```
------------------------------
|tag.id | is_assigned_to_item|
------------------------------
|   1   |          true      |
|   3   |          false     |
------------------------------
```

What could be a query for this using mysql?

Cheers

Sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an outer join to relate the tag table to the tagitems table, including the relevant item_id you specify in the ON clause.

```
select tag.tag_id, 
  (count(tagitems.tag_id) > 0) as is_assigned_to_item
from tag 
  left outer join tagitems on tagitems.tag_id=tag.tag_id and tagitems.item_id = ?
group by tag.tag_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select tag.tag_id, 
case when item.is_assigned_to_item is null then 'false' else 'true' end
from tag left join item on tag.tag_id=item.tag_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  t.id , case when t2i.tagid is null then true else false end
from tags t lef join tagitems t2i on t.tagitemid=t2i.tagid [left join items it om it.id =  t2i.itemid ]
```